# Combining 3 lists of tuples into one new list

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and don't know what to do here.
I have 3 Lists of tuples like:

```
List1 = List[(String,Option[String])]
List2 = List[(String,Option[String])]
List3 = List[(String,Option[String])]
```

The elements in the Lists could look like:

```
List1 = List[("a","1aa2"),("b","1bb2"),("c","1xx2")]
List2 = List[("a","1aa2"),("b",None),("c","1yy2")]
List3 = List[("a","1aa2"),("b","1bb2")]
```

The List could have different .size and the Optional field is sometimes empty.
Now I want to combine these 3 List to a "resultlist" - which would look like this:

```
Listresult = List[(String,Option[String],Option[String],Option[String])]
```

which could look like

```
Listresult = List[
("a" , "1aa2"  ,"1aa2" , "1aa2"),
("b" , "1bb2"  ,  ""   , "1bb2"),
("c" , "1xx2"  ,"1yy2" ,   ""  )]
```

Is it possible to combine lists like that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val map1 = list1.toMap.withDefaultValue("")
val map2 = list2.toMap.withDefaultValue("")
val map3 = list3.toMap.withDefaultValue("")
val keys = List(list1, list2, list3).flatMap(_.map(_._1)).distinct
val resultList = keys.map{k => (k, map1(k), map2(k), map3(k)) }
```

By the way, you say that the second element of your tuples is of type `Option[String]`, but from the example list you posted it is not the case: an empty string is not the same as `None`.
So I assumed that the type of the elemnt is actually `(String, String)` (with potentially empty strings) instead of `(String, Option[String])`.
If in fact the type is really `(String, Option[String])` (meaning that your example list should be more along the lines of `List(("a",Some("1aa2")),("b",None),("c",Some("1yy2"))`), then all you have to change in my code snippet above is to use None as tthe default value:

```
val map1 = list1.toMap.withDefaultValue(None)
val map2 = list2.toMap.withDefaultValue(None)
val map3 = list3.toMap.withDefaultValue(None)
val keys = List(list1, list2, list3).flatMap(_.map(_._1)).distinct
val resultList = keys.map{k => (k, map1(k), map2(k), map3(k)) }
```

Comment: Fits a 100%! Thank you Sir!

Comment: Yes, the type is Option[String] (the list is filled via SQL) I will edit my post

Answer (score 3):

```
val list1 = List(("a","1aa2"),("b","1bb2"),("c","1xx2"))
val list2 = List(("a","1ab2"),("b",""),("c","1yy2"))
val list3 = List(("a","1ab2"),("b","1bb2"))

val combined = list1 ::: list2 ::: list3
```

I think this is the format you'd actually want:

```
//List((a,List(1aa2, 1ab2, 1ab2)), (b,List(1bb2, "", 1bb2)), (c,List(1xx2, 1yy2)))

val result = combined.groupBy(_._1).map { x =>
       (x._1, x._2.map { y =>
        y._2
       })
   }.toList.sortBy(_._1)
```

but if you really want

```
//List(List(a, 1aa2, 1ab2, 1ab2), List(b, 1bb2,"", 1bb2), List(c, 1xx2, 1yy2))
```

then you could use:

```
val result = combined.groupBy(_._1).map { x =>
    (x._1, x._1 :: x._2.map { y => y._2 })
  }.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

Comment: hey, I think this will help me alot!! but still when I do a println i get `(c,List((c,1xx2), (c,1yy2)))
(a,List((a,1aa2), (a,1ab2), (a,1ab2)))
(b,List((b,1bb2), (b,), (b,1bb2)))` how could I read all Strings regarding "a" or simply all String from the 2nd column... sorry im really  new to scala and just worked with arrays in java before this

Comment: I'm surprised this was accepted, as the question asked to have the elements in the final list stored as tuple (of arity 4). I guess OP didn't really know if he wanted tuples or list...? EDIT: oops, accepted solution changed again ^^

Comment: This is a really good answer and fits like 99% for the problem. I'm sorry I can't accept 2 answers on this board

Comment: You can upvote :) and hopefully now it fits perfectly. But I must admit the other answers are nice as well.

Comment: Yeah I will upvote you guys - but it says I can't because my reputation is to low atm (the account was made just 5mins ago)

Answer (score -1):

You could do `list1 ::: list2 ::: list3`

It would be like this:

```
val list1 = List(("a","1aa2"),("b","1bb2"),("c","1xx2"))
val list2 = List(("a","1ab2"),("b",""),("c","1yy2"))
val list3 = List(("a","1ab2"),("b","1bb2"))

val result = list1 ::: list2 ::: list3
```

Comment: This would just paste all tuples in a new list - what I need is a list with a different (bigger) tuple - where the normal "String" element is just shown once